# Is it necessary to use 'void' in function while passing array to a function?

Tags: c

For example, `void` is used here. Could `int` be used in its place instead?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void disp( char ch)
{
   printf("%c ", ch);
}
int main()
{
   char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'};
   for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
   {
       disp (arr[x]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nowhere here is passing an array to a function.

Answer (score 3):

we use `void` before a function when that function returns nothing. So, if your function returns nothing than you can use `void`. If your function return `int` then use `int` before the function name. Basically whatever data type your function returns use that type infront of your function name.

By the way, you are passing character to your `disp` function not the whole array.